# Multiple EditText in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

if I have,say 20 EditText fields in my program...and at a time I want to access 2 of them...then the next 2...then the next 2...and so on....can I do that using an array of ExitTexts??
If yes then can you please provide me a small example...

Accessing each and every EditText separately can be a tedious job...I've tried to implement it in an array...but every time its giving me a Null Pointer Exception...all my IDs are correctly provided...plus the code works when I provide each single EditText separately.

Here is the code::

```
EditText e11,e12,e13,e21,e22,e23,e31,e32,e33,e41,e42,e43,e51,e52,e53,e61,e62,e63,e71,e72,e73,e81,e82,e83,e91,e92,e93,e101,e102,e103;

EditText arr[]={e11,e12,e13,e21,e22,e23,e31,e32,e33,e41,e42,e43,e51,e52,e53,e61,e62,e63,e71,e72,e73,e81,e82,e83,e91,e92,e93,e101,e102,e103};

String ch1="",ch2="',ch3=""; 
for(c=0 to 9)
{
    ch1=arr[(4*c)].getText().toString();
    ch2=arr[(4*c)+1].getText().toString();
    ch3=arr[(4*c)+2].getText().toString();
 }
```

The for loop is giving me a NULL POINTER EXCEPTION...even if i set the values for EditTexts hard coded.

Comment: Array is way to go but without the code and the stack trace, how can anyone help?

Comment: An adapter pattern such displaying a ListView may be the way to go.